# Join query: How to return results from join table2 as an array in the table1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I need to show a list of articles with a full set of tags each article corresponds to. I tried to do this query:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, `title`, `text`, tags.tag_name 
FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` 
on articles.article_id = tags.article_id 
WHERE articles.author_id = 150342
```

However that query returns the same row from table `articles` for every tag as many times as there are tags.

Like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [article_id] => 1
    [title] => title1
    [text] => text1
    [tag_name] => tag1
  )
 [1] => Array
 (
    [article_id] => 1
    [title] => title1
    [text] => text1
    [tag_name] => tag2
 )
 [2] => Array
 (
    [article_id] => 1
    [title] => title1
    [text] => text1
    [tag_name] => tag3
 )
)
```

Is there a way to return tag_name in an array for every article? To look something like this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
 (
    [article_id] => 1
    [title] => title1
    [text] => text1
    [tag_name] => array ([0] => tag1, [1] => tag2, [2] => tag3)
 )
)
```

Comment: Every answer here had a valuable suggestion for me, so I'm upvoting each one. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not array, but you can get comma separated string,

```
SELECT articles.article_id, `title`, `text`, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name )as tg_name
FROM `articles` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` 
on articles.article_id = tags.article_id 
WHERE articles.author_id = 150342
GROUP BY tags.article_id
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you should do two queries or handle/parse the data different way in php.

**Like:**

```
$articles = array();

foreach($query_result as $row) {

  if (!array_key_exists($row['article_id'], $articles))
     $articles[$row['article_id']] = array(
       "title" => $row["title"],
       "text" => $row["text"],
       // etc
       "tags" => array()
     );

  $articles[$row['article_id']]['tags'][] = $row["tag_name"];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First get a result from query and explod  'tag_name' from string to Array:

```
 SELECT A.article_id, A.`title`, A.`text`, group_concat(T.tag_name) a 'tag_name'
    FROM `articles`  A
    LEFT JOIN `tags` T
    on A.article_id = T.article_id 
    WHERE A.author_id = 150342 
    group by A.article_id, A.`title`, A.`text`
```

Example :

```
<?php
// Example 1
$tag_name = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of array in mySQL, but you can have them as comma separated list of tag_names for each artical id

```
SELECT articles.article_id, `title`, `text`, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name) as tag_names
FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `tags` 
on articles.article_id = tags.article_id 
WHERE articles.author_id = 150342 
GROUP BY articles.article_id
```